# No mapping specified for properties MyEntity.MyValue in Set MyEntities

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to set one of my columns in my PDF table/class to *Binary* and It's giving me the following error when I run the command "Update-Database -Verbose" in the *Package Manager Console*:

> No mapping specified for properties PDF.BinaryPDF in Set PDF

My coding:

```
...
using System.Data.Linq;
...

public class PDF
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Binary BinaryPDF { get; set; }

    public int? QuoteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }
}
```

Can any one give me advice on why it's not accepting 'Binary' as a type? Thank you!

Comment: `byte[]` is the recommended data type here.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the comment man. But why would the Binary type not be accepted? I would really like to know

Comment: Probably because supporting `byte[]` is less specific (more versatile). And `Binary` is not much more than a wrapper around a byte array so it's not hard to do the conversion.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick reply. i'll go and do a bit of research on it :)